# What is missing here?

Tags: riddle, steganography, cryptic-clues

> Right now, Puzzling is seeing an unprecedented wave of riddles and ciphers which have completely flooded the main site. I firmly believe in “if you can’t beat them, join them”.
>    Disloyalty!
>   I do know that’s what you will say but let me tell you, to stay relevant, you got to adapt. (Nothing much to see here. Go on.)
>   What we have here is that the site quality suffers and there’s not enough variety. 
>   Absurd! 
>   Very well, if that’s what you think about the problem, then, we can only count the good ones. 
>   Except, post new puzzles!!
>
> On my prefix, you may sit.
>   Soccer player is military(3)
>   My suffix is meant to be hit.
>   odd rat’s painting(4)
>   Element left in God(4)
>   My infix is in chemicals’ name.
>   Plan recreation of a resume(7)
>   Iron has four number(7)
>   On a whole, I am a game.
>
> Oops, the enumerations and the two parts seem to have been jumbled here, that is, I can't confirm whether the enumerations in the clues are correct or not. And there is an extra 6 which you have to use.

The question is, "What is Missing here"?

Hint:

> Synchronous has gotten one half of the steganography part. You need to solve that as a crossword clue. There's another part of the steganography as well.

Comment: *Gasp* Traitor! Benedict Arnold! Tar and feather him!

Comment: Actually this is a good riddle soooo I guess you really aren't a traitor ;) +1. I like how you took C4 and combined it with riddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted by the hint, there is something else hidden in the introduction text:

> The number of words in each setence can be turned into a letter (1 = A, 2 = B, ..., Z = 26) to give **SKATEBOARD**.

The other hidden message, found by Synchronous, ...

> ... says "Riding wave", which probably means **SURFING**.

The affix riddle was solved by ManyPinkHats with some help from Sid, the OP, in chat:

> *On my prefix, you may sit.* **BASE**
>  *My infix is in chemicals’ name.* **SEBA**, (wrong plural of sebum, arguably a "chemical")
>  *My suffix is meant to be hit.* **BALL**
>  *On a whole, I am a game.* **BASEBALL**

I suggested that there was a single word that could go with any of the partial answers, but ManyPinkHats has found the actual connection:

> The partial answers are:
>
>   • Skateboard
>   • Surfing
>   • Karate
>   • Baseball
>
>  These are four of the five new sports for the [2020 Tokyo Summer Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Summer_Olympics). What's missing is the fifth ew sport: **Climbing**.

Comment: Both are correct. Hitman is wrong.

Comment: If the prefix-infix-suffix riddle clues (onfronyy), then the connection could be (svir arj fcbegf sbe Gbxlb gjraglgjragl Bylzcvpf, zvffvat pyvzovat). I can only really see how the prefix works, if so; I don't have a good explanation of infix or suffix yet

Comment: @ManyPinkHats: The connection sounds good. I don't see the construction either. (Base could fit both prefix and infix and the suffix; ball could be the thing that's meant to be hit.)

Answer (score 8):

Soccer player is military should be

> Martial, double definition for "military" and Anthony Martial, a soccer player.

Making the answers to the cryptic clues, plus the extra enumeration

> Martial art gold measure five (6)
>
>   Which seems to be a clue for "Karate".

Answer (score 6):

Cryptics answers:

"odd rat’s painting(4)"

> That clues to ART (anagrammed RAT) -- enumeration should be 3

"Soccer player is military(3)"

> don't know, but enumeration is probably 7

"Element left in God(4)"

> As noted, GOLD (L in GOD)  Enumeration is correct

"Plan recreation of a resume(7)"

> That clues to MEASURE (anagrammed A RESUME)  Enumeration is correct

"Iron has four number(7)"

> That clues to FIVE (Iron -> FE, containing IV (Roman numeral for 4)).  The enumeration should be 4

Comment: All are correct so far.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answers:

Background text

> Taking the first letter of each sentence of the background text in order gives RIDINGWAVE, but I'm not sure how to use this.

Element left in God(4) (confirmed correct guess)

> **GOLD**
>  L(eft) + GOD = GOLD
>  Fun alternative solution if this were a non-cryptic clue:
>  Mercury is a Roman god. The element left of mercury in the periodic table of elements is gold.

Soccer player is military(3) (confirmed wrong guess)

> **MISSILE**
>  Anagram formed from MESSI and (m)IL(itary). As [pointed out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65546/what-is-missing-here/65550#65554) by Clayton Colwell, the enumeration should be 7.

Shaky guess for the affix clues

> ***Hitman: Absolution***
>  I'm assuming that "the two parts seem to have been jumbled here" means that the two words are switched, meaning the clues refer to "Absolution Hitman".
>
>  Prefix: "Abs" are your abdominal muscles, which are used when you sit.
>  Infix: "solution"s are often chemicals mixed together.
>  Suffix: "Hitman".
>  Whole: *Hitman: Absolution* is a video game.

Comment: This is actually a particular type of clue known as [tag:cryptic-clues].

Comment: @noedne Oops, I somehow overlooked that. My answer has been edited.

Comment: I do not understand how the second clue resolves.

Comment: @noedne Messi is a soccer player. I'm relatively new to this, so please tell me if I'm making a mistake.

Comment: 2 is incorrect. I don't do indirect anagrams.

Comment: your first letter-idea is correct. Now, try to find a single-word answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Is the second clue

> A double definition for STRIKER or ARSENAL?

So given the cryptic solving above:

> It would appear the five words given form another clue, possibly
> ART ??????? GOLD MEASURE (5)
> Which seems to clue CARAT.

Need to try the Riley as well.

Comment: there was an error in the puzzle ordering. It's rectified now. And one of your conclusions about the puzzle is wrong.(The new cryptic has the correct enumeration)

Comment: And I forgot to tell that you should read the background text too. There might be some information there.